# Get only one section Laravel4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

How can I get the contents of een section in blade (Laravel 4). This is ideal for using AJAX requests, so I can return just the contents of an section. There are several methods that are related to sections, but they all return nothing.

My question: How can i get the content of an section of an view in my controller?

Comment: I thought Controllers feed views with contents! So, your controller would know what your view has. Otherwise, use jQuery. More information would help

Answer (score 0):

I think I would tackle that by having a view dedicated for the section, then either import that view into another view for your regular page loads, or for AJAX route to a function that just uses the view by itself.

Comment: I don't think that is an great idea. We use the HistoryAPI in browsers to get the next page. With sections, you can specifiy an section to return instead of the whole layout.